# show vertical line indicating time in grafana

Tags: postgresql, plot, graph, grafana

[image]

I am working on the grafana which connect the PostGreSQL database.
I want to plot vertical line to x-axis which connect the point (just like x-intercept).
I plot the points on graph but can't find any option/solution to plot the vertical line.

The x-axis is timestamp and y-axis is values.

I want the line similar to that picture (same as green line)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use annotations to show a vertical line with the timestamp driven by a different query. These are configured in the dashboard settings - not on the panel.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/build-dashboards/annotate-visualizations/

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for are 'Annotation' Queries:

For instance, I have a graph where I want to show vertical lines at 6am every day.

You have to add an 'annotation query' on your dashboard object.

for my logs of

```bash
2023-08-31T00:00:16+0000 849
2023-08-31T06:00:16+0000 848           <---- annotation only on this one
2023-08-31T12:00:16+0000 848
2023-08-31T18:00:16+0000 848
```

my query would look like:

```
{filename="/var/log/my_logs.log"} |= `06:00`
```

[image]

(The time difference is because I am in EST, and the time is UTC)

Tutorials:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9zlzCBoqyc
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/build-dashboards/annotate-visualizations/